# How to create a variable for command-line argument?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file which does some operations with files in the folder. But before, it asks the user whether to perform these operations in sub-folders also. After that the script has the variable %recursive% with the value /r or empty, depending on what the user typed, and runs the command like that:

```
for %recursive% %folder% ...
```

It doesn't work, of course. I cannot make two FOR commands (with recursive parameter and without it), because they'd both have identical code inside.
What would you suggest that I do?
Thanks in advance.

The code is:

```
:LoopStart
set /p recursive="Including sub-folders? [y] or [n]: "
IF /I "%recursive%"=="y" (
    set "myFOR=for /r"
    GOTO :LoopEnd
) ELSE (
    IF /I "%recursive%"=="n" (
        set "myFOR=for"
        GOTO :LoopEnd
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO LoopStart
        )
    ) 
:LoopEnd
%myFOR% %img_dir% %%i in (*.jpg,*.emf,*.png,*.jpeg,*.gif) do (
    echo This is file %%~nxi
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... the ask for recursive has been done ...
...
if defined recursive (
    set "myFOR=for /r %folder%"
) else (
   set "myFOR=for"
)
%myFOR% %%f in ( ....
```

EDIT - OP Code adapted to proposed answer

```
@echo off
    setlocal

    set "img_dir=d:\temp"

:LoopStart
    set /p "recursive=Including sub-folders? [y] or [n]: "

    IF /I "%recursive%"=="y" (
        set "recursive=/r"
    ) ELSE IF /I "%recursive%"=="n" (
        set "recursive="
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO LoopStart
    ) 

    pushd "%img_dir%"
    for %recursive% %%i in (*.jpg,*.emf,*.png,*.jpeg,*.gif) do (
        echo This is file %%~fi
    )
    popd

endlocal
```

pushd and popd commands have been added, not to handle problems in the case of recursion (where the path can be included) but to handle the case of no recursion, as the path is not been included in the sets of files to be processed with the for command.

Comment: It doesn't work in ELSE. I don't know why, it closes the window, even when PAUSE is inserted.

Comment: @Cuder: you are keeping the directory in the for line for non recursive option, which is not allowed. See updated answer. This handles the problem in recursive or non recursive cases. If you decide not to change directory, then for the non recursive case the path to the files should be included in the for file sets, something like `for %%f in ("c:\*.*" "d:\somewhere\*.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

This works.  If the variable is empty then it will be ignored.

```
@echo off
set "recursive="
call :code
set recursive=/r
call :code
goto :eof

:code
for %recursive% %%a in (*) do echo %%a
pause
```

Comment: Yes it does.  test the above script.